# Radio button chosen value retention

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress settings page that has a radio button with 2 given options 'yes' or 'no' but it doesn't seem to retain the chosen option, it deselects after a refresh. It's of great importance that the chosen option stays selected because it triggers the display of an element. I've researched and experimented with the PHP function below but it still doesn't retain the chosen option.

```
function section_footer() {}
    add_settings_field('socialbar', 'Display Social Bar', 'socialbar', __FILE__, 'footer_settings' );

}
    function socialbar() {
        $options = get_option('theme_options');  echo "<input name='theme_options[socialbar]' type='radio' value='yes'  />"; echo 'Yes';  echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            if (isset($socialbar) && $socialbar=="yes") echo "checked";

        $options = get_option('theme_options');  echo "<input name='theme_options[socialbar]' type='radio' value='no'  />"; echo 'No';
        if (isset($socialbar) && $socialbar=="no") echo "checked";

    }
```

Comment: You are _closing_ your `<input>` tag before outputting `checked` – so `checked` is not an attribute of that input element, but just normal _text_ after it. (And your function does not even know a variable `$socialbar`, because it is not in its scope and not passed in as a parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. How do I combine them both safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the "checked" inside of the input declaration.

Change your PHP to the following. You can do the if statement inline using a ternary operator.

```
function socialbar() {
    $options = get_option('theme_options');  echo "<input name='theme_options[socialbar]'   type='radio' value='yes' ".(isset($socialbar) && $socialbar=="yes" ? "checked" : "")." />"; 

    echo 'Yes';  echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    $options = get_option('theme_options');  echo "<input name='theme_options[socialbar]' type='radio' value='no' ".(isset($socialbar) && $socialbar=="no" ? "checked" : "")."  />"; echo 'No';
```

}

Comment: Mituw16 it still didn't retain the chosen value

Comment: Can you post your HTML too? I just took your existing PHP and converted it into a ternary if.

Comment: All PHP in a WordPress function.